# Why was G'Kar's sentence so short?

Tags: babylon-5, laws

In Babylon 5 Season 3 Episode 6, [Dust to Dust](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Dust_to_Dust), G'Kar assaults Londo Mollari with grievous bodily harm; he is subsequently hospitalized.

[image: Londo Assaulted]

However, G'Kar only gets a 60 day sentence. In a normal court, such a sentence would normally be something like 10 years or more. I am NOT talking about:

> The fact that Garibaldi lets him out early because of the secession

I am talking about the **original** sentence pronounced by the judge. The judge specifically discounts Sheridan's request for leniency and insists the crime was premeditated. G'Kar no longer has diplomatic immunity because the Narn regime no longer exists.

Why, in-universe, is his sentence so short?

Comment: Standards for sentencing are dependent on the culture. Some cultures have the death penalty, others find even life without the *possibility* of parole cruel and inhuman. Some place a higher value on human health and life, others place a higher value on property. Some are very lenient on first offenders, others believe in swift punishments. Some are rapidly escalating the punishment in case of repeat offenders, some don't.

Comment: I don't know in which country you live but in Germany bodily harm will not give you even close to 10 years. 10 years & we already are in murder range.

Answer (score 9):

JMS spoke to this point on the [Lurker's Guide](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/050.html) site. He noted that although the sentence seems lenient, it's not **for 60 days**, it's for ***a minimum* of 60 days** (i.e. potentially longer).

> **JMS:** *Actually, just to clarify the legalese, **the judge sentenced him to 'no less' than 60 days; that's the minimum, it could
>   be more.***

I'm not sure that that explains *why* it's so short, but at least it's an acknowledgement that it does seem short. One assumes the judge took into account the extreme provocation offered and the stress that G'Kar has been under.

Comment: I Am Not A Lawyer, but under UK law this looks like "assault causing actual bodily harm", with a [maximum sentence](http://www.inbrief.co.uk/offences/assualt-gbh-abh.htm) of six months. It seems reasonable that G'Kar would be eligible for parole after 60 days, especially since there may be a lot of pressure on space in the station brig.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.msccsp.org/Files/Guidelines/MSGM/guidelinesmanual.pdf) sentencing guideline manual (for the state of Maryland, USA) G'kar's sentence could have been anywhere from probation to 6 months. 60 days seems a bit light to me considering how badly Londo was beaten, but it's within the guidelines.